# Error while passing linked list as an argument

Tags: c, linked-list, bucket-sort

Here is the code for a bucket sort program.

```
typedef struct node_struct {
    double d;
    struct node_struct *next;
} node;
```

I'm using insertion sort to sort the values

```
void insert(double value, int index, node *B[]) {
    node *t;
    if (B[index] == NULL) {
        t = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        t->d = value;
        t->next = NULL;
        B[index] = t;
    } else {
        node *p0, *p1;        
        p0 = B[index];
        p1 = p0 -> next;
        while(p1 != NULL) {
            if (p1 -> d > value) {
                break;
            }
            p1 = p1->next;
            p0 = p0->next;
    }
    t = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    t->d = value;
    t->next = p1;
    p0->next = t;
}

void Bucket_Sort(double A[], int n) {
    int j, index;
    double B[n];
    node *B1;
    B1 = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        B[i] = 0;
    }
    B1->d = A[0];
    B1->next = NULL;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        index = (int) floor(n * A[i]);
        insert(A[i], index, B1);  // This part of the program is where I'm going wrong
    }
    for (int = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%f \n", B[i]);
    }
}
```

When I try calling the insert function, an error occurs saying "expecting struct node ** but the argument is of type struct node *"

But if I call insert function as follows:
    insert(A[i],index,&B1);
Then no error is given while compiling but when I run the program it leads to a segmentation fault. Can someone help me with the confusion?

Comment: well, that's right, `B1` is a pointer to `node`, and your function expects array of pointers to `node`

Comment: the question is confusing. so, how exactly do you call the function when it gives an error you've mentioned?

Comment: I used insert(A[i],index,&B1);

Comment: You can't solve a problem like this by trying random combinations of `[i]`, `*` and `&`. (Well, you *can*, but it's woefully inefficient.) You have not created an array of pointers, and yet you are trying to insert things into it, so of course you are having trouble. Also you do not seem to have a clear idea of what the array should do. You must think more carefully about your design.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert function is indicating b is an array of pointers to node objects.

But you're not passing in an array of pointers, you're calling it with &b1, which is a pointer to a single node (not an array).  And when you uses arrays like that generally you need to pass a count of elements, whereas with pointers to linked list elements you usually use null to indicate the end of the list.

If I were you I would just pass pointers around to deal with everything, and get rid of the `[]` since you're really not passing things properly for an array. E.g. Rather than passing in an index, just pass a pointer to the object of interest.  In more tricky cases you can use `**` pointer to pointer but that requires a *very* solid understand of what you're doing.

Google linked-list example to get ideas how to deal with that properly with pointers. You'll get the idea.

Otherwise be consistent in the way you pass an interpret arrays and pass a count in, and use the count variable in your loops. I'd advise not to try to mix the `[]` form and `*` or `**` paradigms until you get really comfortable with each separately.

```
typedef struct node_struct {
    double d;
    struct node_struct *next;
} node;

void insert(double value, int index, node *b[]) {
    node *t;
    if (b[index] == NULL) {
        t = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        t->d = value;
        t->next = NULL;
        b[index] = t;
    } else {
        node *p0, *p1;        
        p0 = b[index];
        p1 = p0 -> next;
        while (p1 != NULL) {
            if (p1 -> d > value) {
                break;
            }
            p1 = p1->next;
            p0 = p0->next;
    }
    t = (node *)calloc(sizeof(node), 1);
    t->d = value;
    t->next = p1;
    p0->next = t;
}

void Bucket_Sort(double a[], int n) {
    int j, index;
    double b[n];
    node *b1 = (node *)calloc(sizeof(node), 1);
    a1->d = a[0];
    b1->next = NULL;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        index = (int) floor(n * a[i]);
        insert(a[i], index, b1); 
    }
    for (int = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%f \n", b[i]);
    }
}
```

I formatted the program in your question, and went further below. This is more how I see code written in professional code bases and when I do peer code reviews, etc...

Some notes:

• If you use `calloc()` instead of malloc, and your buffer is automatically zeroed.  People usually use `bzero()`, or `memset()` to zero arrays rather than a `for()` loop.

• You can declare an assign a variable such as B1 at the same time and save space/clutter;

• You can declare the variable type inside a for-loop and it will be scoped to just that for-loop. Makes it clear and saves vertical space.

• Don't get too idiosyncratic with your formatting. The programming community is just frustrated by it. There are coding standards at just about any respectable C coding place, and very strict so the code looks clean, readable, easy to understand and maintain, and consistent. If everyone applies their own twist a large coding base becomes an ugly maintenance nightmare.

• Don't add spaces before and after pointers `->` no one does it and it's harder to read by experienced programmers.  Leave spaces after commas, for the same reason you do when writing - separates items visually better - easier to debug, etc...

• Capitals are used for constants.  Camel-case (first letter lower-case and subsequent words first letter capital for example `thisIsMyVariable`), for variables, or underscores `this_is_my_variable`, in C.  Naming arrays with capital letters is tacky and you almost never see it in professional code.

Comment: I made a bunch of edits after initial submission of answer. I'm done now.